# How to Remove Xamarin.Forms (1.4) ListView Header

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am working with the ListView in Xamarin.Forms 1.4 and am wondering if there is a way to remove the header (and footer, for that matter...) from my ListView.  As it is functioning "out of the box", I have extra white space at the top of my ListView, which if the Header property is set to a text value, would display that value; however, when left to the default, or even set to string.empty, the header still occupies space at the top.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

***Edit 1: ***

Just to clarify, I am not using XAML, but straight C#--here is the snippet I am using to create the ListView:

```cs
var listView = new ListView
{
    //Header = string.Empty,
    RowHeight = 160,
    ItemsSource = items,
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ItemCell))
};
```

I left the commented line in for context/reference...

***Edit 2: ***
Here is a screenshot from my iOS simulator demonstrating the issue--notice the top image as I scroll the ListView rolling under the header:

[image]

**UPDATE: Solution**

I marked @FredyWenger's answer as correct, but wanted to provide the actual fix that I implemented to take care of this issue.  By removing/commenting out the lines below, I was able to get rid of the additional space at the tom and bottom of my ListView:

```
Content = new StackLayout
{
    //VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    //HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,

    Children = { listView }
};
```

Comment: I don't see any default Header in my project, and my ListViews don't have a Header attribute. Have you tried removing the attribute altogether or setting it to null? If that doesn't work make a template with 0-height header, see http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/#headerfooter

Comment: Sten, you probably aren't on version 1.4. Try update-package xamarin.forms in your NuGet console.

Comment: Sten, I just updated to 1.4. I don't see a default header size in 1.4 either. I can now add a header and get more space. But if I leave Header blank, it doesn't take space?
Tom, can you post your Xaml?
Is it on all platforms that you get extra space?

Comment: @Rhyous, I updated my question above...I am not using XAML, just C#.  I included a snippet in my edit.

Comment: @Rhyous, I am only targeting iOS at the moment.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of my iOS simulator demonstrating the issue--I apologize for the obnoxious size of the image, not sure how to adjust it easily...

Comment: The list view is inside of a stack layout? if yes then set the padding and spacing of the stacklayout to 0, or if it is not then set the padding of the ContentPage to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the "extra space" on top is coming from the ListView header (LV's don't should show a Header unless you explicitly define one). 
I think it's coming from another setting (mother-)control (e.g. a StackLayout).
I would search there...

Comment: Thanks, @fredywenger!  I added the code that fixed the issue to my question above...